# ADF - Script Activity - Timeout after 30 minutes

Tags: timeout, azure-data-factory

I have a couple of scripts activities and despite the default timeout setup
[image]

It gets a timeout error after 30 minutes.

Any clue?

Comment: Is this set a Query or NonQuery?  Just wondering if that would have an impact.  This type of operation should be NonQuery I think but it looks like the Script activity does not obey the timeout rule there.  You might want to think about making these operations asynchronous as there's not any real value in keeping the pipeline compute (Integration Runtime) and the server running at the same time.  I'm thinking of a scheduled maintenance or "fire and forget" Logic App or something like that.

Comment: It is NoNQuery. And I cannot make it asynchronous because this is part of a loop that do bulk inserts in tables that are used in a second process. But thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

The Script Activity has a currently undocumented time limit of 30minutes. This cannot be changed and the Activity Timeout setting has no effect.

Comment: That's my feeling as well. Hopefully MSFT will fix it soon.

Comment: @lachicazul This is not a feeling; it's a fact I was told from MS.

Comment: As of October 2022 this is now configurable, see the answer from OlehMrB below.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the Script activity to execute DML (Data Manipulation Language) statements like SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, as well as DDL (Data Definition Language) statements like CREATE, ALTER, and DROP operations.

> Currently, the Script activity supports the following data stores:
>
> • Azure SQL Database
>
> • Azure Synapse Analytics
>
> • SQL Server Database
>
> • Oracle
>
> • Snowflake

The General section is similar to other activities with these items:

•   Name - Name of the activity.

•   Description - Comments about this activity (optional).

•   Timeout - Timeout in D.HH:MM:SS format, the default timeout value is 7 days.

•   Retry - Maximum number of retry values.

•   Retry interval (sec) - Specify the number of seconds between each retry attempt, the default value is 30.

•   Secure output - Output from the log file will not be captured if checked.

•   Secure input - Input from the log file will not be captured if checked.

You need to check timeout settings at Source level.

Refer this [article](https://gbamezai.medium.com/how-to-use-script-activity-in-azure-data-factory-f64c2ea8e149) by Tech Zero

Comment: If you read the title: "ADF - Script Activity - Timeout after 30 minutes" you will notice that I'm using the Script Activity ;)

Answer (score 0):

What is the timeout set on the source ? if it always timeout in 30 mins may be thats what is happening . For example you can set the timeout SQL like

USE AdventureWorks2012 ;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'remote query timeout', 30 ;
GO
RECONFIGURE ;
GO

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: No, it's not set up in the source. I have other processes that last hours. It's a script activity problem.

Comment: @HimanshuSinhamsft This does not work for a Script task; it's the ADF Script activity which has an in-built undocumented 30min limit - I was informed from support product group.

Answer (score -1):

Script activity timeout for executing script block is configurable now. For the newly created script activity, the default timeout is 120, but users can change the timeout according to their preference.

Parameter: Script block execution timeout.

[image]

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-script#inline-script

Resolved Github issue: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/94986

Comment: Note the "newly created" bit is important - for my existing pipeline the original 30 minute timeout still seems to take effect, and there is no "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout" in the JSON. A new script activity includes "scriptBlockExecutionTimeout: 120" as expected.